# Does creating Sprite instances without adding them as children decreases performance speed?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, 3d, sprite

I'm building a custom, simple 3D engine in AS3, as simple as possible. It draws everything with Graphics and render it with Bitmap and BitmapData.

For re-ordering the drawing order by z (depth) positions, I use getRelativeMatrix3D of the Transform instance of a Sprite. Here is my question: if I create a lot of Sprite instances but DO NOT ADD THEM AS CHILDREN OF THE STAGE, does it decreases my performance speed?

If it does, then is there a more efficient and useful way of re-ordering WITHOUT ADDING SPRITES AS CHILDREN?

If it doesn't, just tell me.

Thanks! :)

Comment: It won't affect the rendering performance if you don't addChild. It will increase memory if you have lots of objects created. If you have flash builder, you can test the memory consumption. Also be aware of the effects on GC if you have lots of objects created in a short time.

Comment: Thank you for your direct help. By the way, what is GC that you've mentioned?

Comment: Sorry garbage collection. This is something you will need to consider. When you create and kill off lots of objects, flash will reclaim memory, you will need to keep this in check.

Comment: Thank you. But how exactly should I kill off a Sprite instance? There isn't a function like dispose() in BitmapData or likewise.

Comment: Read about GC dude, in flash you would make an object elligible for GC by setting it to null, mySprite = null; Then the GC can collect memory back when it gets round to it, so in a class have a destroy() then set objects to null in there.

Comment: Thank you. Network has been down for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out by @Neil in the comments, objects that are not added to the display list (added to Stage) do not affect rendering performance.

However, creating objects with **new** does always cost time. So if you'd write a function that does nothing but create 1.000 Objects of some kind each frame, you'd likely see a very visible performance drop.

This is true for every language, though, so as a rule of thumb, you should only create **new** Objects where neccessary.

And even re-use objects that are not needed any more. Have a look at the [object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) to see what I mean. As an example, object pools are often used for bullets in a sidescroller. But such things are really part of performance improvements. So if you're short on time and no users are complaining, I would do such optimizations in a refactoring phase. Or you just do it right away, your choice ;)